# What are the EXECUTE, AGAIN, etc. keys for in USB HID usage codes?

Tags: keyboard, usb, hid

I found these in the list of USB HID usage codes:

```
0x74    Keyboard Execute
0x75    Keyboard Help
0x76    Keyboard Menu
0x77    Keyboard Select
0x78    Keyboard Stop
0x79    Keyboard Again
```

(source [here](https://www.freebsddiary.org/APC/usb_hid_usages.php))

What are they meant to be used for? I am familiar with Menu, but the others are lost on me.

Note that these are not media keys; those are in the range 0x31 - 0x37.